# Migrating ASP Membership from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, postgresql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

We are currently in the process of migrating our user database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

We are using the [NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider/) library to allow ASP Membership to work with PostgreSQL. However, the membership table schema in PostgreSQL does not seem to match that in SQL Server. The primary concern being there is no "PasswordSalt" or "PasswordFormat" columns in the PostgreSQL tables.

This causes problems as we are not able to migrate the passwords of the existing users.

Edit: I should mention we are migrating to AWS RDS PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Please provide more details. What have you tried? Code sample?

Comment: I do not have a code sample to provide as this is primarily a data migration issue.